# Fetching websites name contains the HTML code in python 27

Tags: html, mysql, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have facing a problem when I running the python script it download the companies business directories like company name, address, location address and WEB address.

But when this script fetching the websites name of the company like `www.example.com` it just fetch the websites name HTML code instead of fetching the websites name and it also store the HTML code into MySQL server of that current websites.

I have using the following library of Python from BeautifulSoup, lxml, html, hashlib, urllib2 and store the websites name HTML code into MYSQL server like

```
<input><tr><td>www.example.com</td></tr></input>
```

I want to remove this html tag and store the companies web URL like `www.example.com` in to MySQL server

My code is here:

```
for hit in soup2.findAll(attrs={'id' : 'webSite_0'}):
    web = str(hit).replace('<input type="hidden" value="', '')
    web = web.replace('" id="webSite_0" />', '')
if web == "":
    flog.write("\nWebsite extraction... Failed")
    print "None"
else:
    flog.write("\nWebsite extraction... OK")
    print web
    companyObj.setWeb(web)
```

Any solution or any suggestion for how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) two options: using `re` or `BeautifulSoup`.

using **re**

```
import re
cleanse_url = re.compile(r'<[^>]*>')

for hit in soup2.findAll(attrs={'id' : 'webSite_0'}):
    web = str(hit).replace('<input type="hidden" value="', '')
    web = web.replace('" id="webSite_0" />', '')
if web == "":
    flog.write("\nWebsite extraction... Failed")
    print "None"
else:
    web = cleanse_url.sub('', web)  # escape the HTML
    flog.write("\nWebsite extraction... OK")
    print web
    companyObj.setWeb(web)
```

using **BeautifulSoup.Tag.text**

I think that this option is better as `tag.text` strips attributes as well as tags.

```
for hit in soup2.findAll(attrs={'id' : 'webSite_0'}):
    web = hit.text # use beautifulsoup
if web == "":
    flog.write("\nWebsite extraction... Failed")
    print "None"
else:
    flog.write("\nWebsite extraction... OK")
    print web
    companyObj.setWeb(web)
```

Comment: thanks man... but still get error .. but whenever i executes following query it solve my problem but i need to do that with in my code .the queries are UPDATE amt_austria_company SET web = REPLACE( web, '<input id="webSite\_0" type="hidden" value="', '' ) WHERE `web` !=""

UPDATE amt_austria_company SET web = REPLACE( web, '"/>', '' ) WHERE `web` !=""
EI DUITA QUERY DILEI DATABASE THEKE url CLEAN HOYE THIK KOR FELE